# How to send an array of objects in email in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

I need a way to send an array of objects in email, So I can iterate those and create a table in email. I have tried creating email handle but no success.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can but you need to **render a block to email template** like *order&invoice Email*. Magento ***renders order & invoice items render at email using layout & block & template***.

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order
>   area="frontend"}}

In order template, you can see above code.

Means Magento email template is using  layout file `sales_email_order_items` and passing order object using `order=$order`  and sets area using `area="frontend"`

Assume your parameter name is `mydata` a template variable at php code  is

```
templateVars = array(
    'customer_name' => 'John Doe',
    'mydata'   => $yourObjectarray
);
```

using as https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-custom-email-templates/ as the example to show send parameters

- First, create a layout file at frontend>layout folder. Example:
  `my_custom_lays`.
- And then you need to call this layout at the email HTML template
  using`

  `{{layout handle="[MyHandler]" [variableName]=$variableName
  area="frontend"}}`
- After that  create a block and invoke the Block using this layout